# Automake rebuild source file if Makefile changes

Tags: c++, automake, rebuild

When using an autoconf/automake build system if the compiler flags or other variables in a Makefile.am (or even higher level like configure.ac) change, the C++ source files associated with that Makefile will not be automatically rebuilt.  This becomes especially important as we use automake as part of a continuous build system that only recompiles as needed.

My thought was to include Makefile as a dependency for the .o files which would theoretically solve the above issue.  So a couple of questions:

First, is it possible to add a rule like that?  I would prefer to not have to add that custom rule to every single Makefile.am, so something that could be placed into a top-level file (like configure.ac) would be great.

Second, the downside to this approach is that in some cases the change to the Makefile did not actually affect the compilation so I will end up rebuilding when it is not really needed.  I guess I'm willing to live with this (or at least try it to see how painful it is) to have a better guarantee that my builds will be correct, but is there a better way to solve this problem?  I believe clearmake solves this by saving the actual compiler command (along with other dependencies) then comparing the current command with the previous to determine if a file needs to be regenerated.

Comment: Rebuilding things based on a changed makefile variable is wrong, because it breaks things like `make install prefix=/some/other/prefix`, which is necessary for tools like GNU stow.

Comment: @JackKelly I can see that in general that would be a bad thing, but for specific flags like AM_CPPFLAGS changing it seems like a rebuild is required.  For example if I change from including `.../somelib-v2` to `.../somelib-v3` the code will definitely need to be recompiled.  I'd be willing to forgo command line setting of variables if I could get actual Makefile* changes to force recompilation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ccache (`./configure CXX='ccache g++'`, or just add ccache's g++ to the path), spurious rebuilds should be very cheap and still safe. Also make sure never to use the `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` autoconf macro, which makes dependency tracking optional (conditional on the --enable-maintainer-mode flag).

Comment: thanks for the pointer tobu.  seems like ccache will only be invoked when the makefile rules would otherwise invoke the compiler?  so in the case where i change the build flags and automake doesn't detect the need to rebuild, does ccache still help?  sorry if i'm off in the weeds regarding how ccache fits in.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, you still need some rule to make the *.o depend on the Makefiles.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  i'm going to mark the question as unanswered in the hopes that someone can provide an answer for that part of my question.

Comment: `--enable-maintainer-mode` doesn't disable dependency tracking, that's what `--disable-dependency-tracking` does. Maintainer-mode only controls the rebuild rules (processing lex/yacc definitions, remaking `Makefile.in`, and so on): http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/maintainer_002dmode.html